# Kramdown/Rouge doesn't highlight syntax?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, kramdown, rouge

I've been building a small personal site with Jekyll and Rouge isn't highlighting my syntax. Can anyone help explain why?

`_config.yml`:

```
title: My Name
author: My Name
url: "http://myname.com"
baseurl: ""

permalink: /projects/:title

markdown: kramdown
higlighter: rouge

tracking_id: Google Tracking ID

sass:
    style: compressed
    sass_dir: _sass
```

Page with syntax highlighting issues:

````
---
layout: post
title: Python for...Wine Analysis?
blurb: tbd
tags:
    - machine learning
    - python
    - pandas
    - scikit-learn
---

## Imports

```python

import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
from patsy import dmatrices
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn import tree
import statsmodels.api as sm
import os

%pylab inline
```
````

I've followed a couple tutorials, but none have seemed to help. Here's what it ends up looking like:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I used some time to figure out this.

1. install rouge first

`gem install rouge`

2. set up in `_config.yml` file:

`highlighter: rouge`

3. add css file

`rougify help style`

you can run the command in Terminal and see all the provided css templates.

Say you want to use github template, you do this:

`rougify style github > /path/to/css/file.css`

You can also make `scss` file.

4. add this css file to your header.

`<link href="path-to-syntax-highlighter-stylesheet" rel="stylesheet">`

If you want more customization, check → [Add Syntax Highlighting to your Jekyll site with Rouge](https://benhur07b.github.io/2017/03/25/add-syntax-highlighting-to-your-jekyll-site-with-rouge.html)

Comment: steps 1 and 2 did it for me. Just as an addition: when you have a more "exotic" formats like jsx that were not included in the first versions of rouge, you can gem install a newer rouge and edit Gemfile.lock to actually force use (in my case: 3.0.0 instead of 1.11.0). It works like charm then